# How do I move a window based on mvvm data?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a distributed application that runs dozens of instances of the same application. Each instance start up location is set by the start time of the process to get positioned in a grid of windows.  Each instance accepts processing requests from a DB queue and they are managed by a DB store procedure. The third party library used is memory and computationally intense and crashes the application randomly every few hundred requests. There is crash recovery functionality in place and when crashes are detected, the requests of crashed process are re-queued to still running instances of the application. Crash recovery works based on regular writing of each instance to a DB log file.  If an instance of the application has not written to the log in a defined timeframe a crash is detect and recover initiated. As time passes, new application instances are started to replace crashed ones and there start location by start time can place them on top of existing instances' windows. The goal is to have the instance relocate to the new start time order on a regular cycle based on the start times of the running instances. The DB log entries are updated to a Text Box and there is a binding through MVVM pattern.  I need to relocate the windows based on the values going to the Text Box so they shift location by the new start time order of the still running instances.  Examples are based on GUI events and not data bindings. I am at a loss on how to do this.

I have not been able to find an method to accomplish this

The initial location is set using this code

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.Closing += Window_Closing;


    WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.Manual;

    // get window hieght and width
    _windowHeight = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AppHeight"]);
    _windowWidth = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AppWidth"]);

    // get count of apps to fit on screen
    _downAppCount = (int)Math.Floor(System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight / ( _windowHeight + 1 ));
    _acrossAppCount = (int)Math.Floor(System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth / ( _windowWidth + 1 ));

    // get the start order of this process relative to all running to determine screen position
    _currentProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
    int i = 0;
    foreach ( Process proc in Process.GetProcessesByName(_currentProcess.ProcessName).OrderBy(x => x.StartTime).ToArray() )
    {
        i++;
        if ( proc.Id == _currentProcess.Id )
        {
            _processOrder = i;
        }
    }

    // set postion on screen
    this.Top = Math.Floor(( (double)_processOrder - 1 ) / _acrossAppCount ) * ( _windowHeight + 1 );
    this.Left =          (( (double)_processOrder - 1 ) % _acrossAppCount ) * ( _windowWidth  + 1 );

}
```

I hope to shift the location of each instance every times the application dequeues a request and a message goes to the TextBox indicating this.

Comment: Bind the Top and Left properties to properties in your view model.

Comment: Thank you Clemens.  I think understand what you are saying.  I am do not have a lot of experience on the GUI part of WPF.  The applications pushes large volumes of data to a data base from a statistical data modeling package and my GUI is not the focus and so is minimal in its approach. I am quite weak in my understanding of this core aspect of WPF.  If I bind these in the view model wouldn't I need something to initiate the window move or is this handled some auto-magical way?  Thanks again for your assistance! It is vey much appreciated!

Comment: Perhaps start reading here: [Data Binding Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-binding-overview).

Comment: Thanks. I understanding data binding, my issue is how do I move the window based on a bound value.